# Identifying subgroups in a flocking Netlogo model

Tags: netlogo, label

I am working on a flocking model with subgroups of agents that form temporary aggregations. I would like to quantify these subgroups by identifying them with a unique ID and a color. Thus I included the following subprocedure (chain-rule) in the go procedure, right before the tick:

```
to chain-rule
    clear-links
    ask turtles [
    create-links-with other turtles in-radius distance-chain-rule
    ask link-neighbors [ 
    set subgroupID [subgroupID] of myself  
    set color 5 + 10 * subgroupID 
    ]
   ]
end
```

This procedure is correctly linking only those agents within a certain distance, and because links die, it only links agents within what I want to call a subgroup (which is a temporary aggregation). The problem is the labelling: if they just acquire the subgroupID of their neighbors, eventually they all end up with the same subgroupID (and color), regardless of whether the agents still belong to the same temporary aggregation. How to update this labelling just like the links? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not really clear how this is supposed to work. Say turtle A creates links to its neighbours and one of those neighbours is turtle B. Later, B creates links with its neighbours including C, but C is outside the chain-rule distance from A. What subgroup is C supposed to be in? At the moment it is in A, because A has claimed B and then B has claimed C. You obviously don't want it in A, but B can't form a subgroup because it is part of A's subgroup. Also, if a turtle ends up with 5 links, then that means it is potentially part of 5 different subgroups - which one is the one you want?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I do want C to belong to A's subgroup because my definitoin of subgroup is all those agents that can be linked by distances of less than a certain cutoff (in my code, "distance-chain-rule"). Regardless of who is the original agent that gives a subgroup its ID, I would like them to share the same ID while they belong to the same subgroup. When they split, they should change their ID. At the moment, my implementation is simply spreading the ID permanently, regardless of whether agents still belong to the same subgroup.

Comment: Okay. Do you already have a procedure to recognise when they split? If you don't have too many agents, you could (every tick) create links between any pair of nodes within your pairing distance and use the cluster procedure in the network extension to identify subgroups, then delete the links. The advantage of this approach is that it automatically deals with the case when a small group simultaneously separate from the main group, which is much harder than when a single agent splits off.

Comment: Thanks! the nw:weak-component-clusters is working perfectly to identify the subgroups as I wanted them.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I found with help by [JenB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4346285/jenb), using the network extension's nw:weak-component-clusters. This procedure identifies, on each tick, the weak components of a network of agents linked by a given distance.

```
extensions [ nw ]

to chain-rule
   clear-links
   ask turtles [ create-links-with other turtles in-radius distance-chain-rule ]
   set subgroups nw:weak-component-clusters
   show subgroups
end
```